# Converting CURRENCY to a long

Tags: winapi, automation, currency, long-integer

How can I convert CURRENCY type to a long type?

I need to be able to do this because I want to put the value of the CURRENCY type into a sprintf using %d

I'm having a hard time with this one, help is appreciated :)

Comment: C++ Doesn't have a CURRENCY type, so we'd need to know more about what kind of structure it is

Comment: Can you add the definition of the class CURRENCY and we can advice on how to exactly create the overloaded operator and accessors which will allow you to do what you need.

Comment: Use VariantChangeType to convert it to a string, sprintf it with %ls.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to cast a [CURRENCY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221223%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) value to a long. As you can see in the documentation, a currency is simply a 64 bit integer, storing 1/10000ths of a currency unit. With unit I mean Dollar, British Pound, Euro, etc. Not pennies, cents and the like. All you have to do is to do this: `long value = (long)currency.int64`. Remember that if the value in the member `int64` is larger than `LONG_MAX` or smaller than `LONG_MIN`, then you will get truncation errors.

Why do you need to convert the value into a long? Can't you use the `CURRENCY` union as is?

Answer (score 0):

If the currency is a string, you can use

```
sscanf(currency, "%d", &myLong);
```

If it is any other basic data type, you can just typecast such as

```
long myLong = (long)currency;
```

If you have more information on the data type, please edit it into your post.

Answer (score 0):

CURRENCY is a class which is defined somewhere in your code (i.e. it is not a native C++ type).

Your class may already have the capability to cast to int (or long) if it is written by someone else.   You can try to figure that out by (1) readinh the header files or (2) compileing this

```
    CURRENCY mymoney;
    printf("%d",static_cast<long>(mymoney));
```

and see if the compiler let you get away with that -- and if it does then most likely there is already a cast operator defined for the class.

Many people don't like you to use sprintf in C++ code, but prefer you to use streams.   If so there may be a `<<` operator defined instead -- you can try to determine that by (1) reading the include files, or (2) compiling this code

```
    CURRENCY mymoney;
    std::cout << mymoney << std:: endl;
```

If not you may have to write the code to overload the `<<operator` and/or the long cast operator on the Currency class to return the values you need for stream output and casting to other types.